# How to use a special sequence in substitute pattern in re.sub

Tags: python, regex, substitution

I have a string, in which I'd like to substitute each `[` by `[[]` and `]` by `[]]` (at the same time). I thought about doing it with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
re.sub(r'(\[|\])', '[\1]', 'asdfas[adsfasd]')
Out: 'asdfas[\x01]adsfasd[\x01]'
```

But I'm not getting the desired result -- how do I make the `re.sub` consider `\1` in the pattern as the first matched special group?

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\[|\])', r'[\1]', 'asdfas[adsfasd]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `r` prefix for your replacing regex as well, otherwise `\1` will be interpreted as a hex literal:

```
In [125]: re.sub(r'(\[|\])', r'[\1]', 'asdfas[adsfasd]')

Out[125]: 'asdfas[[]adsfasd[]]'
```